# I need help for a school project

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in HTML and Javascrit and I need to scrool sections using two buttons. I wrote a code which works with one two sections. How can I use it with more than two?

```
<body>
<button id="a1" onclick="f1()"><img width="100%" height="100%"
<button id="a2" onclick="f2()"><img width="100%" height="100%"
</body>

function f1() {
var elmnt1 = document.getElementById("sez1");
elmnt1.scrollIntoView();
}
function f2() {
var elmnt2 = document.getElementById("sez2");
elmnt2.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about having target element's `id` as a parameter?

```js
function scrollTo(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
onclick="scrollTo('sez3')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to write a generic function which will call 'scrollIntoView' on the clicked Element, you can do something like:

```
<body>
<button id="a1" onclick="genericfunc(event, 'id1')"><img width="100%" height="100%" /></button>
<button id="a2" onclick="genericfunc(event, 'id2')"><img width="100%" height="100%" /></button>
</body>
<script>
  function genericfunc(event, id) {
     var elmnt = document.getElementById(id);
     elmnt.scrollIntoView();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
<body>
  <button id="a1" onclick="f1('divID1')">
  <button id="a2" onclick="f1('divID2')">
</body>

function f1(divID) {
  var elmnt1 = document.getElementById(divID);
  elmnt1.scrollIntoView();
}
```

However, there are several ways to scroll, for example:

Via Anchor

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

location.href = "#myDiv";
```

Via offsetTop

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div id="myInnerDiv"></div>
</div>

let myElement = document.getElementById('myInnerDiv');
let topPos = myElement.offsetTop;

document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollTop = topPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function GetDisplayed(id) {
 var element = document.getElementById(id);
 element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
#sez1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 1000px;
   left: 2000px; ;
 }
#sez2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2000px;
  left: 1000px; ;
 }
#sez3{
   position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 2500px; ;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<button id="a1" onclick="GetDisplayed('sez1')">Button 1</button>
<button id="a2" onclick="GetDisplayed('sez2')">Button 2</button>
<button id="a3" onclick="GetDisplayed('sez3')">Button 3</button>

<section id="sez1">First section</section>
<section id="sez2">Second section</section>
<section id="sez3">Third section</section>

</body>
```